How do I go about removing a cabinet in an existing kitchen (that has a countertop)
I was trying to remove this cabinet to install a fridge. What all do I need to considered? The top looks like I may need to cut it. And learned the left one may be glued to the other cabinet.



Will that pipe allow sufficient depth?

It will, barely. It will stick out beyond the other cabinet door by 1/2”.

where are you going to plug it in

Speaking in rather general terms, base cabinets are installed in a sequence like this:

install a toe kick/base, if this is not already part of each cabinet box
set each cabinet box on the base (or floor)
join adjacent cabinet boxes together: screw the faces or boxes together in the front at least, and maybe other areas too
screw a countertop base layer (plywood or particle board) to the tops of the cabinet boxes
install finished countertop

Removal of a cabinet box without fully reversing the steps above, ie "disassembling in reverse order," is going to be a bit of a fight. For one thing, you can see the sharp point of a screw coming down from the countertop base layer into the top of the cabinet box. You can't unscrew that without removing the countertop. Instead you'll have to demolish the cabinet box to a greater or lesser degree to free it from that screw. That might mean literally breaking the wood apart, or maybe cutting out a section of wood around the screw, etc. There are likely to be several more problems like this.
You should expect that the cabinet box will be damaged during removal such that it won't be possible to re-install later if the fridge is removed.

my oscillating multitool will make short work of screws coming down like that, in fact, that cabinet can be easily deconstructed. The issue will be if there is sufficient support after...

This was my thought. The fridge is like 11.75” so I can try to only cut the right side, cut into the spacer about 1/2” and it should fit without having to remove the left panel. And the height of it is only 34” so I can try to leave the top part. So between leaving the top, back, and left, I’m hoping the support would be ok. Something like this: https://imgur.com/a/Uvc35tg. Should this work?

Also given the small width of the cabinet, my multitool doesn’t quite fit in the space to easily to cut. Trying to think of alternatives.

Remember to that nominal width of appliances are often very nominal. Measure, repeatedly, before making any assumptions and allow extra space for error and to maneuver in. And if you encounter any resistance, stop, before you do enough damage to the fridge that you can't exchange it for a smaller model. (I've seen that mistake made; appliance skins are often thin metal and can be damaged if they rub against a corner.)

Good call on the measure X times. I just remeasured the pipe depth in the back, and the right side is definitely much further back than the right. It’ll stick out an extra 3/4” than I had anticipated.

Hopefully the height of the fridge doesn't interfere with the overhang of the counter.

What you have looks to be a "custom" cabinet layout.  That is a whole row of cabinets is built as one unit and installed as a single unit.  Removing the section you want can be done, but it involves a great amount of precise cutting.
Unless you have experience in doing the "surgical removal" that is needed you will most likely not be happy with the results. Perhaps think about removing the entire custom unit and installing new cabinets to suit your needs.
As an aside: Where do you plan to get electric for the refrigerator.

Thanks for the comment. How can you tell if it’s a single unit? I can see the seams between each cabinet unit and there are screws between them.
The sink is to the left and there’s an extra outlet in there and the amp and load should be enough to support. If not, there’s an outlet right some the counter that I can draw from.

I could not see a seam between the cabinet in question and the cabinet to the left. ( could be picture quality) still a seam could just be the material used to cover the box. A seam on the right only would be common for a fill panel to the next 90deg. facing cabinet.   Good that you got the electric figured.
